# Prove $abc+abd+acd+bcd\le\frac{1}{27}+\frac{176abcd}{27}$ for $a+b+c+d=1$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> Let $a,b,c$, and $d$ be four positive reals satisfying $a+b+c+d=1$. Show that
> $$abc+abd+acd+bcd\le\frac{1}{27}+\frac{176abcd}{27}.$$

I tried the inequality between $27abc$ and $(a+b+c)^3$ but it didn't help me

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: try : You can try to show with your constraint $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}-\left(\frac{1+\frac{176\cdot16}{27}\left(abcd-\frac{1}{4^{4}}\right)}{16\left(abcd\right)}\right)\leq 0$$ wich is a rewriting

Comment: This is undoubtedly an interesting exercise, but it falls a bit short of [what is expected from a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). At least a number of reviewers think that way. You may think that the policies only apply to hoomework problems, but it was decided a long time ago that the standards should be the same for all questions, including contest (training) questions.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1748125/823641.

---

Define $f(a,b,c,d) = abc+abd+acd+bcd - \frac{1}{27} - \frac{176abcd}{27}$.
We have $f(1/4,1/4,1/4,1/4) = 0$.
We shall show that $f(1/4,1/4,1/4,1/4)$ is the maximum among all $a,b,c,d$ satisfying the conditions.

Suppose not, and assume that another value of $(a,b,c,d) = (x,y,z,w) \neq (1/4,1/4,1/4,1/4)$ corresponds to the maximum $f(x,y,z,w)$.
WLOG, we assume that $x \neq y$.
We have
\begin{align}
&f(\frac{x+y}{2},\frac{x+y}{2},z,w) - f(x,y,z,w) \\
=~&(x-y)^2(z+w)/4 - \frac{176zw}{27 * 4}(x-y)^2 \\
=~& \frac{(x-y)^2}{4}(z+w-\frac{176zw}{27}),
\end{align}
where
$$\frac{(x-y)^2}{4} > 0.$$
If $z+w-\frac{176zw}{27} > 0$ then we are done because in that case we have $f(\frac{x+y}{2},\frac{x+y}{2},z,w) > f(x,y,z,w)$, completing the proof by contradicting the assumption of maximality.

Now, we assume that
$z+w-\frac{176zw}{27} \leq 0$,
then we have
$$f(x,y,z,w) = xy(z+w - 176zw/27) + (x+y)zw - 1/27$$
$$\leq (x+y)zw - 1/27 \leq (1 - t)t^2/4 - 1/27,$$
where we have used the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality and $t = z+w$.
Let $g(t) = (1 - t)t^2/4 - 1/27$.
It is easy to check (by $g'(t)$) that $g(t)$ achieves its maximum at $t = 2/3$ with $g(t) = 0$.
Therefore, we have $f(x,y,z,w) \leq 0$, completing the proof.

Answer (score -2):

We rewrite the inequality as :

$$f(a,b,c,d)=-\left(\ln\left(a\right)+\ln\left(b\right)+\ln\left(c\right)+\ln\left(d\right)+\ln\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}-\frac{176}{27}\right)\right)\geq -\ln\left(1/27\right)$$

We use the [equal variable method](https://r.search.yahoo.com/_ylt=AwrkPDOlOg5jzBcPSBsk24lQ;_ylu=Y29sbwNpcjIEcG9zAzEEdnRpZANTRlNZRlRuZXdfMQRzZWMDc3I-/RV=2/RE=1661905701/RO=10/RU=http%3A%2F%2Femis.maths.adelaide.edu.au%2Fjournals%2FJIPAM%2Fimages%2F059_06_JIPAM%2F059_06_www.pdf/RK=2/RS=D5f.v9ohcNQUSt8Oxl0Zvsykjdc-) corollary 1.5 as :

$$a+b+c+d=1$$

$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}=constant$$
$$f\left(x\right)=-\ln\left(x\right)$$ define :

$$g\left(x\right)=f'\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)$$

then we have :

$$g''(x)>0$$

So the $f(a,b,c,d)$ is minimal for $d\geq c\geq b \geq a>0$ and $d=c=b=x$

Remains to show the inequality for $x\in[0,1/3)$ :

$$x^{3}\left(1-3x\right)\left(\frac{3}{x}+\frac{1}{1-3x}-\frac{176}{27}\right)-1/27\leq 0$$

Or :

$$1/27(3x-1)(4x-1)^{2}(11x+1)\leq 0$$

Can you end now ?

---

---

Adding remark for another proof :

For $0<a\leq b\leq c \leq d$, $a+b+c+d=1$ and $b=c=0.25$ we have the inequalities :

$$\left(abcd\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{9\left(1+\frac{5\left(a-0.25\right)^{2}}{1+a}\right)}{1-a}\right)-\frac{1}{27}-\frac{176}{27}abcd\right)\geq abcd\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}\right)-\frac{1}{27}-\frac{176}{27}abcd$$

Wich is a one variable inequality .

Now and again fixing $b=c=0.25$ and introducing the variable $u,v>0$ such that $a+u+v+d=1=a+b+c+d$ and $0<a\leq b\leq c \leq d$ we have :

$$abcd\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}\right)-\frac{1}{27}-\frac{176}{27}abcd\geq auvd\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{u}+\frac{1}{v}+\frac{1}{d}\right)-\frac{1}{27}-\frac{176}{27}auvd$$

using the previous inequality .

Now it misses one equality case so to be continued...

Edit 01/09/2022 :

We have the following inequalities for $0<a<0.3\leq b \leq c \leq d$ and $a+b+c+d=1$ :

$$0\geq \left(abcd+\frac{a^{2}\left(0.25-a\right)^{2}}{2\left(2-4a\right)}\right)\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{9}{\left(d+c+b\right)}-\frac{176}{27}\right)-\frac{1}{27}\geq abcd\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}-\frac{176}{27}\right)-\frac{1}{27}$$

And we can use the same strategy fixing two new variable $u,v$